# I can not understand a sentence with "zoo of the new"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I am a statistics student. The following is extracted from my textbook:

> The study of probability and expectation shows one way of coping with randomness and this book will build on probabilistic foundations to find the strongest possible links between claims and their random underlying stocks. The current state of truth is, however, unfortunately complex and there are many false trails through this zoo of the new. Of these, one is particularly tempting.

The above is the full sentence, and I especially can't understand the following parts. What is meant
by "zoo of the new"?

> The current state of truth is, however, unfortunately complex and there are many false trails through this zoo of the new.

Is the meaning of "zoo" similar to "field"? Thank you!

Comment: "Zoo" is a metaphor for a varied collection.  "The new" refers the nature of the items in this collection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because my head will split open if I read "zoo of the new” one more time in a single post.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Thank you for your feedback. I've realized that it's not appropriate to post words-meaning questions here. Both Hot Licks and Anton's answers are helpful. I have already understood the role of "zoo" and "new" in context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage reflects the impact of a book and television series  “The Shock of the New” by Robert Hughes:

> Hughes went on to make acclaimed films about Goya and Gaudi, as well as the series American Visions, his personal view of American art. In 2004 he made The New Shock of the New, which looked at developments since 1980. The Shock of the New continues to be influential: Hughes died in 2012 but not before The Guardian named the spin-off book – which is still in print - among its 100 greatest non-fiction books.
>
> [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/historyofthebbc/anniversaries/september/the-shock-of-the-new)

The phrase “of the new” thus acquired overtones of formative influence, of seeing things in a new way, of challenging convention.

In your example, the phrase is applied to the collection {described as a zoo} of possible statistical ideas relevant to the links between claims and stocks. The author is hinting at the novelty and innovative importance of these ideas.